# Internacionalizar plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Olá! Estou utilizando um dataTable padrão do jquery, contudo mesmo com o charset setado para "UTF-8" as partes da tradução com acentos são representadas por: �. Alguém saberia uma solução para consertar essa internacionalização?

Minha head está assim:

```
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Categorias</title>

        <!-- Núcleo Bootstrap CSS-->
        <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Customização de fontes-->
        <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Page level plugin CSS-->
        <link href="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Estilo de customização do template-->
        <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#dataTable').dataTable( {
                    "language": {
                        "url": "traducoes/traducao_table.txt"
                    }
                } );
            } );
        </script>
```

O arquivo de traduções está assim:

```
{
    "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
    "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ".",
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
    "sProcessing": "Processando...",
    "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
    "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sNext": "Próximo",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior",
        "sFirst": "Primeiro",
        "sLast": "último"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
    }
}
```

Comment: O charset já está setado na head da página.

Comment: Pode ser um zilhão de coisas diferentes isso. Sem você postar mais detalhes sobre o seu projeto, inclusive coisas do servidor que você está utilizando e cabeçalhos HTTP das requisições e respostas dele, fica difícil te ajudar.

Comment: A pergunta não dá muitos detalhes. Erick, por favor, nos dê mais detalhes para que possamos lhe ajudar. Informe-nos todos os detalhes da página, a linguagem (PHP, C#, Java etc.), as opções que vc colocou no plugin etc. Seja sempre bemvindo, mas dá uma lida aqui [nesta página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona mais ou menos as coisas.

Comment: Estou utilizando o php para compor minha página que está alocada em um servidor da web. Editei a pergunta para tentar atender a requisição feita por vcs. O trecho de código da <head> acontece após a definição de um title e após setar o charset.

Comment: Eu tentaria algumas coisas, por exemplo: Setar o charset na chamada do javascript do datatable e abrir o js do datatables no notepad++ e na aba formatar converter para o charset desejado.